# Is it possible to use 'dch -r' but NOT end up in an interactive editor?

Tags: packaging

I'm trying use `dch -r` to update the DEBFULLNAME, DEBEMAIL, and TIMESTAMP in a debian/changelog for automated building of a package.

Normally, I'd use [dch](http://manpg.es/dch) with `-r` to do this.  But this drops me into an interactive editor.  Is it possible to suppress that and just save it immediately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha!  Just specify an empty release string!

```
dch -r ""
```

Comment: You can also set the distroseries without invoking the editor by adding the --distribution argument.  This has always proven useful to me in switching from UNRELEASED.  For example: 'dch -r "" --distribution quantal'