# Dch non-interactive mode

Tags: packaging

I'm trying to find a way to run `dch` in non-interactive mode, in order to incorporate the `debian/changelog` file creation and manipulation within a shell script.

It seems that only when running it with the argument `-r ""` it works (as specified [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114835/is-it-possible-to-use-dch-r-but-not-end-up-in-an-interactive-editor)). However, I need to use different arguments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the problem,

It appears that `dch` will open an editor if it doesn't get all the information that it considers mandatory. So in order to create a `debian/changelog` without opening an editor I've found that the following combination of options is sufficient:

```
dch --create --distribution unstable --package "pkgpkg" --newversion 0.0.0.0-0.test "some nice message"
```

Comment: `dch -n "some nice message"` is enough.

Comment: @uav the `-n` flag doesn't work if you need to create a new change log for the first time: `dch: fatal error at line 573:
Cannot find debian/changelog anywhere!
Are you in the source code tree?
(You could use --create if you wish to create this file.)`

Comment: Working exelent, thanks

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you intend to do with it. `dch` picks up on the `VISUAL`/`EDITOR` variables to determine the editor, and the only condition is that it understand/ignore an initial option of the form `+n`. So I can do:

```
$ cat edit.sh 
#! /bin/bash

shift
sed -i 's/UNRELEASED/trusty/' "$@"
$ VISUAL='bash edit.sh' dch -i
$ head -3 debian/changelog
mypackage (1.24ubuntu1) trusty; urgency=medium

  *
```

And get reasonably automated operation.